# How to calculate the definite integral of the complex function $\frac{1}{(a+ib + (a-ib)x^2)}$ for $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$

Tags: complex-integration

How do I calculate the following integral:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a+bi+(a-bi)x^2}dx$,

where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$a+ib=r e^{ic}, r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2},~\frac{a+ib}{a-ib}=e^{2ic},$$
then $$I=\frac{1}{a-ib} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2+e^{2ic}} =\frac{e^{ic}}{r} e^{-ic} \tan^{-1}x e^{-ic}|_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Comment: Why is the limit of $\arctan(z)$ at $\pm \infty$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ (meaning $|z| \rightarrow \pm \infty$) is the same as the limit of $\arctan(x)$ where $x \rightarrow \pm \infty \wedge x \in \mathbb{R}$?